# Changing bar chart colours with reactive data in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Sorry if this question has already been asked!

I am writing a shiny application that looks at the attendance rate of students at after school activities. The data is organised by date, type of activity, student, and by whether or not the student attended the session (a binary 1 for yes and 0 for no). There is also a "Rate" column which is just attended times by 100 (which I use for the bar chart, see below). Here is a sample of the data:

```
Date           Activity          Name                Attended   Rate
01/02/2017     Tutoring          John Doe            1          100
01/02/2017     Music             Jane Smith          0          0
02/02/2017     Drama             John Doe            0          0
```

At the moment I'm plotting the data on a bar chart. I'm plotting average attendance rate by student, using a reactive dataset (mydata()) which filters by the Date and Activity columns. Here is the code for the barchart:

```
output$attendancerate <- renderPlot({
ggplot(mydata(), aes(Name, Rate)) +
stat_summary(geom = "bar", fun.y="mean") +
coord_flip() +
ylab("Attendance Rate (%)") +
stat_summary(aes(label=round(..y..,1)), fun.y=mean, geom="text",hjust=-.2)
```

I am particularly interested in calling attention to students with an attendance rate of 75% or less. I'd like to have those students with 75% or less filled in red, and those with 75% or above, filled in green.

I can't seem to work out how do to this in a way which reacts to changes in the data!

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions for this question.

One of them is using `barplot()` in R.

Please try this:

```
output$attendancerate  <- renderPlot({
dataRead_bar<-mydata()[,c('Name',"Rate")]
cols <- c("red", "green")[(dataRead_bar$Rate > 0.75) + 1]  
barplot(dataRead_bar[,c(2)], names = dataRead_bar$Name,
        xlab = "Name", col=cols)

})
```

Please let me know if you have any question! I don't know your reactive data set so I didn't verify if my code is working fine or not, but it should provide you a clue to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! When I run the code I'm not getting the averages?